# How to get description of object from python django backend to AJAX in front end?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

In  models I have specified  object description

```
def __unicode__(self): ...............................
```

And I want to see this description in my dynamic drop boxes generated with Ajax.
But I just get [object Object] in dropdown.

My data flows in following way:

1-I have sterilizer in my api

```
class LeaseTermSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model=LeaseTerm       
    fields = '__all__'
```

2-I have api method in view

```
@api_view(['GET']) @csrf_exempt def get_leaseterm(request, tid):
    leasetermobj = LeaseTerm.objects.filter(lease=tid,is_active = True)
    leaseterm_serializer = LeaseTermSerializer(leasetermobj, many=True)
    response = Response(leaseterm_serializer.data)
    return Response(response.data,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

3-In my template I build it like this

```
function getleaseterm() {

    //get a reference to the select element
    $select = $('#leaseterm');
    //request the JSON data and parse into the select element
    var l_id = ($("select[name='lease'] option:selected").attr('value'));
    l_url = "/api/get_leaseterm/"+l_id+"/";

    $.ajax({
      url: l_url,
      dataType:'JSON',
      success:function(data1){
        //clear the current content of the select
        $select.empty();
        $select.append('<option value="-1">Select term </option>');
        //iterate over the data and append a select option

        $.each(data1, function(key, val){
          $select.append('<option value="' + val.id + '">' + val + '</option>');
        })
      },

    });

}
```

Problem is that the  "val" value I display in dropdown if I I don't specify what field I want to show will display [object Object] for all the values in dropdown when I want it to display description of object I have specified for my model.

How can I see my object description in my dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your case `val` is the `serializer.data`(means json object by your serializer declare) so as result you see `[object Object]`, you are confusing with django template where you can use such way. 
but you can, add charfield to your serializer, and use it

```
as_char = serializers.CharField(source='__unicode__')
```

in html:

```
$select.append('<option value="' + val.id + '">' + val.as_char + '</option>');
```

Answer (score 1):

It displays the `[object Object]` because your `get_leaseterm` endpoint returns a list of `LeaseTerm` serialized as JSON objects and you are adding the object itself to the `option` element content.

The python methods you defined are not available on the client side. To solve your issue you have 2 solutions:

- Implement the logic you have in the `__unicode__` method on the client side in JavaScript.

or preferably:

- modify your Serializer to include the output of that method in a new `field` (Probably setting that method as a `@property`).